# OSError when trying to open rgb image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am using the flir_image_extractor.py (https://github.com/Nervengift/read_thermal.py) to extract temperatures a series of images. I got it working for one image at a time, but when I try to run the script for all files within a folder I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\u_value_module.py", line 438, in <module>
    export_temperatures()
  File ".\u_value_module.py", line 434, in export_temperatures
    flir.process_image(images)
  File "C:\Users\sai.peri\Documents\u_value_module\flir_image_extractor.py", line 62, in process_image
    self.rgb_image_np = self.extract_embedded_image()
  File "C:\Users\sai.peri\Documents\u_value_module\flir_image_extractor.py", line 102, in extract_embedded_image
    visual_img = Image.open(visual_img_stream)
  File "C:\Users\sai.peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2822, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x038543C0>
```

Following the trace it looks like the `visual_img=Image.open(visual_img_stream)` is causing the issue. When I put print checks to see what it is doing I get the following output True

```
True <_io.BytesIO object at 0x038543C0>
True
True
True
True <_io.BytesIO object at 0x038543C0>
```

Where true means a successful step was completed. It seems like it is trying to load the image into the same memory location. At this point I get the OSError. The images that work are black and white (all 3 color channels are the same) and when I use a thermal image (orange-blue) color pallet it gives me this error. I am not sure why this is happening because all the data it extracts is with the exiftool -b command which should work no matter what image you are using as long as the metadata is there. My code looks like this:

```
def export_temperatures():
    '''
    This function will go through the list of images in the images/original folder and then extract temperature
    values from it and export to the csv folder
    :return: None
    '''
    flir = flir_image_extractor.FlirImageExtractor()

    for images in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\sai.peri\\Documents\\u_value_module\\images\\original'):
        #Look in directory to see how many jpg files are there
        os.chdir('C:\\Users\\sai.peri\\Documents\\u_value_module\\images\\original')
        flir.process_image('DJI_0334.jpg')
        os.chdir('C:\\Users\\sai.peri\\Documents\\u_value_module\\exported\\')
        flir.export_thermal_to_csv(images + '.csv')

export_temperatures()
```

Comment: I would contact the author of the script and file an issue with them, as it seems that's where the problem is.

Comment: The creator doesn't seem to be updating the post often. Is there a way I could go about solving this myself?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be within the function `extract_embedded_image(self)` function. But I realized that in my situation I am not using a RGB image. The `extract_thermal_image(self)` function was the one that read from the exiftool output. So by commenting out the `self.rgb_image_np = self.extract_embedded_image()`

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57812235/2) to the question [OSError when trying to open rgb image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812235/oserror-when-trying-to-open-rgb-image) by the OP [sai peri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11302526/sai-peri) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>